# Confirming PGPKey in Launchpad could not import the OpenPGP key %{fingerprint}

Tags: launchpad, openpgp

So I have followed the Getting Set Up of the Ubuntu Packaging Guide.

I have generate my key and sent it to the key server

```
pg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --send-keys myidhere

gpg --list-keys --keyid-format long --fingerprint
/home/odroid/.gnupg/pubring.kbx
-------------------------------
pub   rsa4096/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX 2020-03-18 [SC]
      Key fingerprint = 3AB0 XXXX 5AAB XXXX BE32  XXXX 8C4D XXXX 45A9 XXXX
uid                 [ultimate] Walter Zambotti <zambotti@iinet.net.au>
sub   rsa4096/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX 2020-03-18 [E]

gpg --send-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com XXXXXXXX
gpg: sending key XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX to hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com
```

Generated a ssh-key

Created a launchpad account and entered both the openpgp key and the ssh key.

I received an email (using enigmail 4 thunderbird) and followed the link.

I was asked by launchpad to enter my pass phrase to confirm the openpgp key and received this response:

Launchpad could not import the OpenPGP key %{fingerprint}. Check that you published it correctly in the global key ring (using gpg --send-keys KEY) and that you entered the fingerprint correctly (as produced by gpg --fingerprint YOU). Try later or cancel your request.

Found a lot of similar posts but none with my specific issue.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

It appears it was just delays in the key servers. I waited a few hours and tried again and received this message:

The key 4096R/3AB0XXXX5AABXXXXBE32XXXX8C4DXXXX45A9XXXX was successfully validated.

Maybe launchpad should not send the email if it isn't ready!!!